# Is there a simple way to get an id associated with an aggregate like min and max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I always brute force my way through the solution to the problem of getting an id associated with an aggregate operation like min and max through some ugly sql code. I am just wondering if there is a correct/clean way to solve this problem. Suppose you have the following:

```
SELECT 1 AS groupid, 1 AS id, 100 AS val
INTO #a
UNION
SELECT 1, 2, 50
UNION
SELECT 1, 3, 75
UNION
SELECT 2, 2, 120
UNION
SELECT 2, 4, 22
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 45
```

> NOTE#1: `id` is unique within a `groupid`
>
> NOTE#2: `val` can have the same values so in that case the `id` column
>   will be the first id corresponding to `val`

Suppose I want the result to look like:

```
groupid | min_id | min_val | max_id | max_val
   1        2         50       1        100
   2        3         22       2        120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation or window functions.  For instance, you can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct group_id,
       min(val) over (partition by groupid) as min_val,
       first_value(id) over (partition by groupid order by val asc) as min_id, 
       max(val) over (partition by groupid) as max_val,
       first_value(id) over (partition by groupid order by val desc) as max_id
from t;
```

Alas, SQL Server does not support `first_value()` as an aggregation function, so this uses the `select distinct` short-cut.

Comment: This is very clean! Love it

Answer (score -1):

Use [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and simple aggregation functions like this

```
SELECT groupid, MIN(id) AS min_id, MIN(val) as min_val, MAX(id) AS max_id, MAX(val) as max_val 
FROM table
GROUP BY groupid
```